# Optimize Snowflake query to not perform table scan

Tags: optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake view which is built on top of multiple tables like below:
View definition:

```
create or replace view all_names_view (name, id,last_seen_time_id_utc) as 
(select * from catagory_1
union all
select * from catagory_2
union all
select * from catagory_3
union all
select * from catagory_4
....
....
union all
select * from catagory_200);
```

The data is such a way that a `name` can be found in only one of the underlying tables. For example: `name='Sam'` can be found only in table `category_4` but when I try to look for `name='Sam'`, Snowflake is scanning multiple tables and a lot of processing is happening during that process.

I would like to optimize query in such a way that when I try to find a name, it only checks for that one tables and returns the result.

The `id` column in the view corresponds to the id number on the table name.

Comment: I think you are overestimating Snowflake's ability :). its impossible for any DBMS to know the data scattered into multiple tables and search accordingly. Search in one table, it will act like you are saying. Its like you give a key to a lock in a bunch of locks, someone need to try every locks with the key because he/she doesnt know which lock belongs to your key but you.

Comment: In theory you could write a Table UDF to do this that would loop through all the tables and stop when it finds a record. However, this would only be (potentially) quicker than the View if it happened to find the record in one of the early tables it processes - the later in the list of tables it finds the record the longer it will take, obviously, and the less likely this approach will be faster than the View

Comment: How long does that query take to execute?